# Manually trigger Scala Metals build import in (n)vim

Tags: scala, vim, scala-metals

As per the title, how can I manually trigger the [build import query](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vim.html#importing-a-build) from Scala Metals in (n)vim?

Metals usually queries upon writing changes to `build.sbt` or related files, but when I decide to cancel to query (empty entry) or write again before the previous import is done, it fails to query again. So, I'd like to be able to manually trigger a build import. But how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `coc-metals` (deprecated, no longer maintained)

```
:CocCommand metals.build-import
```

And in `nvim-metals`:

```
:MetalsImportBuild
```

Comment: Thanks, great help. I am using `coc-metals`, so that's all I needed to know. :)